Django static files showing ONLY if debugger is started (with DEBUG=True)
I am using daphne as Django server with the integration from daphne to runserver in settings.py
I have a strange error since yesterday with static files with DEBUG=True, (so, no, it's not another case of static files not found when DEBUG=False ! ;)
They don't show up when I'm running python manage.py runserver but when I run the app using the debugger from VS Code, then they show up.
So my setup is working in some way but only under debugging...
In settings.py, I have:
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
...
]

my launch.json is:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Django",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": ["runserver"],
            "django": true,
            "autoStartBrowser": false,
            "justMyCode": false,
        }
    ]
}

so it also runs the same command (runserver).
The static files are stored in the static// directory of each app.
Any idea?
EDIT:
BASE_DIR = Path(file).resolve().parent.parent

urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


Hmm, what is BASE_DIR set to? Also show the url patterns you've added for static / media files.

Please [edit] your post with any clarifications instead of just replying in comments.

@Abdul Aziz, post edited

Your urls.py static config lookup is incomplete, you only set up for media files lookup,
On your project urls.py insert this code snippet below there mate, and make sure you imported from django.conf.urls.static import static.

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Since we cannot see your static configuration in your settings.py file, make sure you have configured it, if not then take this code snippet below, and paste it in your static files setup in your settings.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# create the folder called `static` in your project root directory
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = 'static_root'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
# create the folder called `media` in your project root directory
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True




Lastly, ensure that the daphne server you are using is the first application you added to the list of INSTALLED_APPS  to avoid unnecessary behavior of your program.

Thanks @Blaisemart. Several remarks. 1. my media are already working very well with the same config as you gave above  2. I already tried  urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) and it doesn't work. For me, that's normal, it's useless because it is what is done by default by the static app already 3. I gave my settings.py for static (see above) 4. Adding the static dir in STATICFILES_DIR is forbiden in the Djanngo documentation.  5. My config is working when I start the server with the debugger: I can't see what in your answer could explain that.

Hello @Olivier, kindly note that I was just pointing out the possible scenarios you need to check which could lead to the error you are having so that you can easily troubleshoot and find it out. Also try and check the static template tags of your projects, possibly that could be the cause of the error. PS: I thought you had already deployed your -project, and that is why I had to give you the suggestion of using STATICFILES_DIR, if your question is well-detailed enough, I wouldn't have mentioned that.

Hi @Blaisemart, you tried to help me so sorry if my answer did offend you, it was not on purpose. Only 600 chars in a comment so you have to make it short ;) Actually, I have deployed my project but in a different envt. What do you mean by checking the static template tags? It works with the debugger so how could they be wrong?
